# How to access community logged in user in UrlRewriter

Tags: apex, community

```
global class CommTestUrlRewriter implements Site.UrlRewriter {
    global PageReference mapRequestUrl(PageReference myFriendlyUrl) {

       // Always the guest user
       System.debug(UserInfo.getName());
       return null;
    }

    global List<PageReference> generateUrlFor(List<PageReference> mySalesforceUrls) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

It seems that the guest user is always in UserInfo within the UrlRewriter, even though the request is made by a user logged in to the community. Once forwarded to the actual controller (all server side), the logged in community user is in UserInfo.  Is it possible to access the logged in community user somehow in the UrlRewriter? If so, how?

(Note: I don't have a great use case. Just trying it.)

Comment: Hi @Peter , I would like to check with you that I see there is no suggestions here. I have similar situation now. Please advice. Much appreciated any suggestions.

Thanks